# Seeing a mirage through mirror?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

Okay, I am not really good in physics (rather terrible), but nonetheless.
So, I was just wondering if you can see a mirage, is there something special in our eyes that we can see it or what? I mean, if I am looking a mirage (or into a mirage or at a mirage, whichever is correct) and then instead of directly looking at it, I take a plane mirror and turn my around and look into mirror would I still see the mirage? How would the situation differ if I had a concave/convex mirror?

Comment: Mirage is an optical phenomenon. That doesn't imply something's fishy with ur eyes. If you see a mirage, you'd see whatever you do. 

Whatever mirror you use, the situation would be just as you are seeing a real object.

Why do you think a mirage should behave differently?

Comment: @Cheeku:
I don't know man. I am terrible at physics. I was watching some sci-fi and it was about illusion and universe and what not, and they were like you `and it (the universe) looked at itself through mirror and found that the reality is just illusion, just like a mirage.`

Comment: Well, that was pure sci-fi then.

Comment: Vampires don't have a reflection in mirrors, right?

Comment: @b_jonas:
yeah, I've heard that, but is this really true? I mean if they were for real, (not the people who pretend to be Gothic and sh**) so will they not see themselves in mirror?

Comment: @Razort4x I'll let you know when I'm done counting the angels dancing on the head of my pin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the mirage is an optical illusion, the mirror will not change thas effect. You are still using your optics while looking through a mirror. A mirror is simply reflecting your eyes back towards the mirage. A mirror will not change this effect. If you were to use say a camera or video-camera, then the results would be very similar. Overall the mirror will not change the outcome of the mirage.

Comment: So, how would the result differ if I was using a camera?

Comment: You see the mirage with your eyes, and the camera records it. In most cases the camera is just a tool to help you see and will not change the illusion of the mirage.

Comment: @JackMoody Didn't you mean to say instead : "If you were to use say a camera or video-camera, then the results would NOT be dramatically different"

Comment: a camera is inspired from our eye. a camera works just like our eye. so if you can see a mirage you can click a picture of it. search for some images and you will see.